# Is there a way to sort a list so that rows with the same value in one column are evenly distributed?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hoping to sort (below left) by sector but distribute evenly (below right):

| Name | Sector. | Name. | Sector |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | A | 1 |
| B | 1 | E | 2 |
| C | 1 | H | 3 |
| D | 4 | D | 4 |
| E | 2 | B | 1 |
| F | 2 | F | 2 |
| G | 2 | J | 3 |
| H | 3 | I | 4 |
| I | 4 | C | 1 |
| J | 3 | G | 2 |

Real data is 70+ rows with 4 sectors.

I've worked around it manually but would love to figure out how to do it with a formula in excel.

Here's a more complete (and hopefully more accurate) idea - the carouselOrder is the column I'd like to generate via a formula.

| guestID | guestSector | carouselOrder |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 |
| 3 | 1 | 9 |
| 4 | 1 | 13 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 | 6 |
| 7 | 2 | 10 |
| 8 | 2 | 14 |
| 9 | 3 | 3 |
| 10 | 3 | 7 |
| 11 | 3 | 11 |
| 12 | 2 | 18 |
| 13 | 1 | 17 |
| 14 | 1 | 20 |
| 15 | 1 | 23 |
| 16 | 2 | 21 |
| 17 | 2 | 24 |
| 18 | 2 | 27 |
| 19 | 1 | 26 |
| 20 | 1 | 29 |
| 21 | 1 | 30 |
| 22 | 1 | 31 |
| 23 | 3 | 15 |
| 24 | 3 | 19 |
| 25 | 3 | 22 |
| 26 | 3 | 25 |
| 27 | 3 | 28 |
| 28 | 1 | 32 |
| 29 | 4 | 4 |
| 30 | 4 | 8 |
| 31 | 4 | 12 |
| 32 | 4 | 16 |

Comment: Why is does `J` sector 3 come before `H` sector 3? Also, is it possible for a lower sector to contain less Names?

Comment: I don't understand your requirements, would you provide the corresponding output? Thanks

Comment: Need: XL version and if you want method, formulas or VBA

Comment: @P.b actually H should come before J  and 2nd E is an F

Comment: oh yes, sorry did that on my phone manually and completely screwed up order! Although in reality the order doesn't matter (it's to distribute adults at a careers fair so the students get a variety as they move from table to table).

Comment: The names are guests at a careers fair - the 4 x sectors are roughly finance/business, creative, health/science, tech/engineering. Was hoping that there was some way of sorting with an arrayformula or similar.

Comment: Your edit is really a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try the following approach that *doesn't require to create a helper column*. I would like to explain first the logic to build the recurrence, then the excel formula that builds such recurrence.

If we sort the input data **Name** and **Sector.** by **Sector.** in ascending order, the new positions of the **Name** values (letters) can be calculated as follow (*Table 1*):

| Name | Sector.Sorted | Position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | `1+4*0=1` |
| B | 1 | `1+4*1=5` |
| C | 1 | `1+4*2=9` |
| E | 2 | `2+4*0=2` |
| F | 2 | `2+4*1=6` |
| G | 2 | `2*4*2=10` |
| H | 3 | `3+4*0=3` |
| J | 3 | `3+4*1=7` |
| D | 4 | `4+4*0=4` |
| I | 4 | `4+4*1=8` |

The new positions of **Name** (letters) follows this pattern (*Formula 1*):

```
position = Sector.Sorted + groupSize * factor
```

where `groupSize` is `4` in our case and `factor` counts how many times the same **Sector.Sorted** value is repeated, starting from `0`. Think about **Sector.Sorted** as groups, where each set of repeated values represents a group: `1`,`2`,`3` and `4`.

If we are able to build the **Position** values we can sort **Name**, based on the new positions via `SORTBY(array, by_array1)` function. Check [SORTBY](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sortby-function-cd2d7a62-1b93-435c-b561-d6a35134f28f#:%7E:text=The%20SORTBY%20function%20sorts%20the,Channel%20starting%20in%20July%202020.) documentation for more information how this function works.

Here is the formula to get the **Name** sorted in cell `E2`:

```
=LET(groupSize, 4, sorted, SORT(A2:B11,2), sName,
 INDEX(sorted,,1),sSector, INDEX(sorted,,2),
 seq0, SEQUENCE(ROWS(sSector),,0), mapResult,
 MAP(sSector, seq0, LAMBDA(a,b, IF(b=0, "SAME", 
  IF(a=INDEX(sSector,b), "SAME", "NEW")))), factor,
 SCAN(-1,mapResult, LAMBDA(aa,c,IF(c="SAME", aa+1,0))),
 pos,MAP(sSector, factor, LAMBDA(m,n, m + groupSize*n)),
 SORTBY(sName,pos)
)
```

Here is the output:

[image: sample excel file]

### Explanation

The name `sorted` represents the input data sorted by **Sector.** in ascending order, i.e.: `SORT(A2:B11,2)`. The names `sName` and `sSector` represent each column of `sorted`.

To identify each group we need the following sequence (`seq0`) starting from `0`, i.e. `SEQUENCE(ROWS(sSector),,0)`.

Now we need to identify when a new group starts. We use `MAP` function for that and the result is represented by the name `mapResult`:

```
MAP(sSector, seq0, LAMBDA(a,b, IF(b=0, "SAME", 
  IF(a=INDEX(sSector,b), "SAME", "NEW"))))
```

The logic is the following: If we are at the beginning of the sequence (first value of `seq0`), then returns `SAME` otherwise we check current value of `sSector` (`a`) against the previous one represented by `INDEX(sSector,b)` if they are the same, then we are in the same group, otherwise a new group started.

The intermediate result of `mapResult` is:

| Name | Sector Sorted | mapResult |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | SAME |
| B | 1 | SAME |
| C | 1 | SAME |
| E | 2 | NEW |
| F | 2 | SAME |
| G | 2 | SAME |
| H | 3 | NEW |
| J | 3 | SAME |
| D | 4 | NEW |
| I | 4 | SAME |

The first two columns are shown just for illustrative purpose, but `mapResult` only returns the last column.

Now we just need to create the counter based on every time we find `NEW`. In order to do that we use `SCAN` function and the result is stored under the name `factor`. This value represents the factor we use to multiply by `4` within each group (see *Table 1*):

```
SCAN(-1,mapResult, LAMBDA(aa,c,IF(c="SAME", aa+1,0)))
```

The accumulator starts in `-1`, because the counter starts with `0`. Every time we find `SAME`, it increments by `1` the previous value. When it finds `NEW` (not equal to `SAME`), the accumulator is reset to `0`.

Here is the intermediate result of `factor`:

| Name | Sector Sorted | mapResult | factor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | SAME | 0 |
| B | 1 | SAME | 1 |
| C | 1 | SAME | 2 |
| E | 2 | NEW | 0 |
| F | 2 | SAME | 1 |
| G | 2 | SAME | 2 |
| H | 3 | NEW | 0 |
| J | 3 | SAME | 1 |
| D | 4 | NEW | 0 |
| I | 4 | SAME | 1 |

The first three columns are shown for illustrative purpose.

Now we have all the elements to build our pattern for the new positions represented with the name `pos`:

```
MAP(sSector, factor, LAMBDA(m,n, m + groupSize*n))
```

where `m` represents each element of **Sector.Sorted** and `factor` the previous calculated values. As you can see the formula in Excel represents the generic formula (*Formula 1* see above). The intermediate result will be:

| Name | Sector Sorted | mapResult | factor | pos |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | SAME | 0 | 1 |
| B | 1 | SAME | 1 | 5 |
| C | 1 | SAME | 2 | 9 |
| E | 2 | NEW | 0 | 2 |
| F | 2 | SAME | 1 | 6 |
| G | 2 | SAME | 2 | 10 |
| H | 3 | NEW | 0 | 3 |
| J | 3 | SAME | 1 | 7 |
| D | 4 | NEW | 0 | 4 |
| I | 4 | SAME | 1 | 8 |

The previous columns are shown just for illustrative purpose. Now we have the new positions, so we are ready to sort based on the new positions for **Name** via:

```
SORTBY(sName,pos)
```

### Update

The first `MAP` can be removed creating an array as input for `SCAN` that has the information of `sSector` and the index position to be used for finding the previous element. `SCAN` only allows a single array as input argument, so we can combine both information in a new array. This is the formula can be used instead:

```
=LET(groupSize, 4, sorted, SORT(A2:B11,2), sName,
 INDEX(sorted,,1),sSector, INDEX(sorted,,2),
 factor, SCAN(-1,sSector&"-"&SEQUENCE(ROWS(sSector),,0),
   LAMBDA(aa,b, LET(s, TEXTSPLIT(b,"-"),item, INDEX(s,,1),
     idx, INDEX(s,,2), IF(aa=-1, 0, IF(1*item=INDEX(sSector, idx), aa+1,0))))),
 pos,MAP(sSector, factor, LAMBDA(m,n, m + groupSize*n)),
 SORTBY(sName,pos)
)
```

We use inside of `SCAN` a `LET` function to calculate all required elements for doing the comparison as part of the calculation of the corresponding `LAMBDA` function. We extract the `item` and the `idx` position used to find previous element of `sSector` via:

```
1*item=INDEX(sSector, idx)
```

we are able to compare each element of `sSector` with previous one, starting from the second element of `sSector`. We multiply `item` by `1`, because `TEXTSPLIT` converts the result to text, otherwise the comparison will fail.

Comment: Thanks very much, that seems to have absolutely done what I wanted. I *kind* of understand it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

When using Office 365 you can use the following in `D2`: `=MOD(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:A11),,0),4)+1`

This create the repetitive counter of the sectors 1 to 4 to the total count of rows in your data.

In `C2` use the following:

```
=BYROW(D2#,LAMBDA(x,
 INDEX(
       FILTER($A$2:$A$11,$B$2:$B$11=x),
       SUM(--(D$2:x=x)))))
```

This filters the Names that equal the sector of mentioned row and indexes it to show only the result where the row in the filter result equals the count of the same sector (`D2#`) up to current row.
[image]