# How to classify my binary classified data in excel in pair and unpair rows

Tags: excel, sorting

How to classify my binary classified data in excel in pair and unpair rows
I want my data to be classified one class in a pair row than the other class in an unpair row and so on for all data. Here a sample input and the expected output:

| Text | Gender | Sorted | Input |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BB | M | BB | M |
| AA | F | AA | F |
| CC | F | DD | M |
| DD | M | CC | F |
| AB | F | CD | M |
| BA | F | AB | F |
| CD | M | DC | M |
| DC | M | BA | F |

where the last two columns are the expected result sorted evenly by `M`, `F`. A valid solution could be also starting from `F` instead of `M`. The **Text** column is irrelevant related to the sorting algorithm. It is just required as part of the output to indicate the input sorted.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: the expected output is like in the photo above i want it to be ordered that way (male then female then male, etc or the opposite female/male/female/male etc.)

Comment: Thanks and @AveryLily what is the input then so I can see the logic to transform the input into the output. Is the `Text` the same but one with `M` and another with `F` or the `Gender` has nothing to do with the `Text`?

Comment: no the text is always different I have classified my texts (input) into M= Male or F= Female. I will use this excel to classify other texts into M/F but i want to order it first like in the picture above.

Comment: provided a solution based on my understanding of  your question. If you want to understand the solution I would recommend to check the answer I provided to a similar problem (added the link in the answer), you can find there all the details of the logic behind

Comment: thank you so much for your help.. the problem is I have never used these functions i tried to add the number column and when i add the function you gave me i get invalid function.. here is a screenshot https://files.fm/u/fszcf4ktb

Comment: check the `HSTACK` but I would recommend to add a column with the same number of rows for consistency, you can do it in several ways, replacing `SORTY(sInput, pos)` with `HSTACK(SORTY(sInput, pos), rng)` or `HSTACK(LET(...), rng)` where `rng` represents the excel range in column format you want to add, for example: `H2:H9`.

Comment: i tried the last function that you added but it's always telling me that the Let function is invalid here's a screenshot https://files.fm/u/p2tfkmaad can you plz upload the first and last step to check what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Avery you haven't provided in your question any excel version constraint (you can add a tag to your question specifying it). If there is no version constraints we assume the latest one. [Here](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/functions/updates.htm) you have excel functions organized by version. Probably you have an older version. `LET` is from Office 2021, but the solution uses other new functions such as `SCAN`. I don't know how to attack this problem for an older version.

Comment: what about google sheet ... are these function available in google sheet? thank you so much for your answers

Comment: Avery, I guess all of them are available except `LET` you need to check.  The solution would be to remove it and replace all the corresponding name values by their definitions. The formula will be longer but it works. You can try. For example: `=LET(a, A2, b, A3, a+b)` instead: `=A2+A3`.

Comment: okay i think i understand you i will try that out then and i will let you know here.. thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Just adapting the idea used in the answer (under [Microsoft Office 365](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/functions/updates.htm)) provided by me to the question: [Is there a way to sort a list so that rows with the same value in one column are evenly distributed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74165034/is-there-a-way-to-sort-a-list-so-that-rows-with-the-same-value-in-one-column-are). In cell `E2` enter the following formula:

```
=LET(groupSize, 2, sorted, SORT(HSTACK(A2:B9,XMATCH(B2:B9,{"M","F"})),3), sInput,
 FILTER(sorted, {1,1,0}),sGenderNum, INDEX(sorted,,3),
 seq0, SEQUENCE(ROWS(sGenderNum),,0), mapResult,
 MAP(sGenderNum, seq0, LAMBDA(a,b, IF(b=0, "SAME",
  IF(a=INDEX(sGenderNum,b), "SAME", "NEW")))), factor,
 SCAN(-1,mapResult, LAMBDA(aa,c,IF(c="SAME", aa+1,0))),
 pos,MAP(sGenderNum, factor, LAMBDA(m,n, m + groupSize*n)),
 SORTBY(sInput,pos)
)
```

*Simplification 1*: There is no need to add a numeric column on the fly representing the gender, but the formula from previous question needs to be changed a little bit. It would be enough to add a `SWITCH` statement in the last `MAP` function. If you want to start with `F` interchange the letters in the `SWITCH` statement or the associated numbers.

```
=LET(groupSize, 2, sorted, SORT(A2:B9,2), sGender,INDEX(sorted,,2),
 seq0, SEQUENCE(ROWS(sGender),,0), 
 mapResult,MAP(sGender, seq0, LAMBDA(a,b, IF(b=0, "SAME",
  IF(a=INDEX(sGender,b), "SAME", "NEW")))), 
 factor, SCAN(-1,mapResult, LAMBDA(aa,c,IF(c="SAME", aa+1,0))),
 pos,MAP(sGender, factor, LAMBDA(m,n, SWITCH(m, "M",1, "F",2) + groupSize*n)),
 SORTBY(sorted,pos)
)
```

*Simplification 2*: For this particular case after sorting in ascending order the gender, there is only one change from `F` to `M`. So we can remove the first `MAP` on previous solution, finding where this change happens (`changeIdx`). So it can be simplified as follow:

```
=LET(groupSize, 2, sorted, SORT(A2:B9,2), sGender,INDEX(sorted,,2),
 changeIdx, XMATCH("M", sGender), seq, SEQUENCE(ROWS(sGender)),
 factor, SCAN(-1,seq, LAMBDA(aa,c, IF(c= changeIdx,0, aa+1))),
 pos, MAP(sGender, factor, LAMBDA(m,n, SWITCH(m, "M",1, "F",2) + groupSize*n)),
 SORTBY(sorted,pos))
```

The previous approach works only for the binary case (two values for the genders). See **Disclaimer** note at the end

and here is the output:

[image: sample excel file]

### Explanation

#### First Formula

Please check the referred answer to understand the logic. If you want to start first with Female (`F`) in `XMATCH` interchange the letters `M`, `F`. The mentioned solution requires to have number instead of letters for the column to sort, so I adapted the input adding an additional column on the fly via: `HSTACK` with the equivalent numbers representing the gender (`0`,`1`). The column representing the numbers is the following:

```
XMATCH(B2:B9,{"M","F"})
```

**Disclaimer**: This is a simpler case than the referred question, so maybe there are easier ways to do it. Because this is just a particular case it easier to adapt it than to start from scratch and we can guarantee it works. If I have time I will try to simplify it but so far it is good enough.